# For a positive integer $n\geq 2$ with divisors $1=d_1<d_2<\cdots<d_k=n$, prove that $d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k<n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> IMO 2002 P4
> Let $n\geq 2$ be a positive integer with divisors $1=d_1<d_2<\cdots<d_k=n$.
> Prove that $d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k$ is always less than $n^2$, and determine when it is a divisor of $n^2$

I am trying this question but I run out of ideas, could someone give a little hint or a suggestion? Please, without giving me the solution.

I am trying to use the fact that the product of $d_i$*$d_{i+1}$ is a divisor of $n^2$ (and they are all different) and maybe try to use the formula for the sum of divisors to see if this specific sum is less than $n^2$

Comment: You will get good hints if you include what you have tried so far. Also please avoid using pictures for critical parts of your post. It may not be legible for people using screen readers. Please take the time to type out the question using Mathjax.

Comment: It's the same as $$\frac{n^2}{d_1d_2}+\frac{n^2}{d_2d_3}+\cdots+\frac{n^2}{d_{k-1}d_k}$$isn't it?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, because it must be $\displaystyle d_{k+1-i} = \frac{n}{d_i}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint 1: How large can $d_{k-1}$ be as a function of $n$?  What about $d_{k-2}$?

Hint 2: Let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $n$.  What can you say about $d_{k-1}$ in terms of $n,p$?  What’s the largest (proper) divisor of $n^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Since $d$ is a divisor of $n$ if and only if $n/d$ is, we have $$d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k=\left(\frac{n^2}{d_1d_2}+\frac{n^2}{d_2d_3}+\cdots+\frac{n^2}{d_{k-1}d_k}\right)\leq n^2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{d_j}-\frac{1}{d_{j+1}}\right)<\frac{n^2}{d_1}=n^2$$ $$\tag*{$\left[\text{since $\frac{1}{d_jd_{j+1}}\leq\left(\frac{d_{j+1}-d_j}{d_jd_{j+1}}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{d_j}-\frac{1}{d_{j+1}}\right)$}\right]$}$$

For the second part, let $n$ be composite and $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $n$. Then we have $$d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k>d_{k-1}d_k=\frac{n^2}{p}$$ Now if $N=d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k$ is a divisor of $n$ then we must have $\frac{n^2}{N}\mid n^2$. But $p>\frac{n^2}{N}$ is a contradiction since $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $n^2$. So $N\mid n^2$ if and only if $n$ is a prime.

Comment: I think that $$d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k=n^2\left(\frac{1}{d_1d_2}+\frac{1}{d_2d_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{d_{k-1}d_k}\right).$$Am I wrong?

Comment: Why $$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{d_j}-\frac{1}{d_{j+1}}\right)=\frac{1}{d_1}?$$I think the result of the sum should be $$\frac{1}{d_1}-\frac{1}{d_k}=1-\frac{1}{n}.$$ Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Angelo you're absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes! Sorry to everyone for making such mistakes though.

Comment: You are welcome :-)