# sum of products of consecutive divisors of a number is smaller than the number squared

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $n>1$ be natural. Let $$1=d_1<d_2<\ldots<d_k=n$$ be its all divisors. Prove that $$s:=d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k<n^2$$ and determine when $s$ divides $n^2$.

For example:
$n=12$, divisors: $1,2,3,4,6,12$. Then $$s=1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+4\cdot 6+6\cdot 12 = 2+6+12+24+72=116 < 12^2$$ and $s$ doesn't divide $n^2$.

My attempts

The second part is easy. Namely, $s\geq d_{k-1}d_k = \frac{n^2}{d_2}$, which is the largest proper divisor of $n^2$ (since $d_2$ is the smallest divisor of $n$ greater of $1$ (hence also of $n^2$). Therefore, if $k>2$, that is, if $n$ isn't prime, then $s>\frac{n^2}{d_2}$ and doesn't divide $n^2$. If $n$ is prime than $s|n^2$.

My idea of the first part:

- It's easy to show the inequality $s<n^2$ provided $2d_i\leq d_{i+2}$, since then, considering the summands from right to left, one can see that $s\leq n^2/2+n^2/4+\ldots<n^2$.
- One can think of $n^2$ as the area of a square and $s$ as the sum of the areas of the rectangles. I don't know how to use it.
- Using the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means we obtain
  $$s\leq \frac 12+d_2^2+d_3^2+\ldots+d_{k-1}^2+\frac 12d_k^2.$$ This shows that it remains to show that
  $$d_1^2+d_2^2+\ldots+d_{k}^2< \frac 12\left(3n^2+1\right).$$ There's a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) for such a sum.
- Maybe some induction could be used. I tried to prove that it suffices to show that the conclusion is true for $n/d_2$, without any success.

Comment: the bit with $\frac{3}{2}  n^2 $  fails  sometimes, first examples are $n=60$     and $n=120$

Comment: If we assume all possible divisors, then we will have $n*n/2 + n/3*n/4 + n/5*n/6 + ... = n^2 (1/2 + 1/12 + 1/30 + 1/56 + ...)  = n^2 \log{2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For a positive integer $n\geq 2$ with divisors $1=d_1&lt;d_2&lt;\cdots&lt;d_k=n$, prove that $d_1d_2+d_2d_3+\cdots+d_{k-1}d_k&lt;n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795384/for-a-positive-integer-n-geq-2-with-divisors-1-d-1d-2-cdotsd-k-n-prove-t) . Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24d_1d_2%2Bd_2d_3%2B%5Ccdots%2Bd_%7Bk-1%7Dd_k%5Clt%20n%5E2%24&p=1). There's also the AoPS thread [IMO ShortList 2002, number theory problem 2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17325p118687).

Comment: ~Will Jagy, You're right.

Comment: ~sku, The denominators won't be $1\cdot 2$, $3\cdot 4$, $5\cdot 6$, but $1\cdot 2$, $2\cdot 3$, $3\cdot 4$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, great remark about Approacho. Before posting this problem I've been looking for a solution on StackExchange, but I used phrased like 'sum of products of divisors'.

Comment: @Mateo FYI, this [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/602049) has some useful information specifically about using Approach0, with the overall thread providing details about other ways to search this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the worst-case scenario: $n$ is enormous, and is divisible by all integers up to some large $k$. If we look at the *largest* divisors of $n$, they must be $n, n/2, n/3, \cdots n/k$.

Then the largest term in the sum is $n \cdot n/2 = \frac12 n^2$. The next largest term is $n/2 \cdot n/3 = \frac16 n^2$. The next terms will have $12, 20, 30, \cdots$ as their denominators: these are the pronic numbers (of the form $n^2+n$). The sum of the reciprocals of the pronic numbers converges to $1$:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{1}{i^2+i} = 1 \implies n^2 = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{n^2}{i^2+i} > \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{n^2}{d^2+d} = s$$

The greater than sign appears due to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic; we know $n$ has a non-infinite number of divisors. Therefore $n^2 > s$.